# Failed to fetch .... Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

**Environment :**
- OS: Ubuntu 19.10
- Docker Version:  19.03.8, build 
- Docker Compose Version: d 1.25.4,

**Docker Command Executed** :

docker-compose -f development.yml build

**Actual Result**

Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/source/by-hash/SHA256/f99962052ff8f88ecb0ca0a22b07aa069b984d346a0c9097b7d39f5ade9edb29 Hash Sum mismatch

Answer (score 1):

i tried these two commands to resolve this issue

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo sed -i -re 's/\w+\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```